# Undefined error getting in javascript (React Native)

Tags: javascript, react-native, undefined

I am storing particular key value in Database. But, While fetching the key value, getting **undefined** error.

```
await DbHandler.fetch(codeStatus)
  .then((result) => {
    const codeEnabledObj = result[0];
    console.log('codeEnabledObj', codeEnabledObj);
    let codeEnabled = false;
    if (codeEnabledObj && codeEnabledObj.length > 0) { // this code not executing at all.
      codeEnabled = codeEnabledObj[0].isEnabled;
    }
    console.log('codeEnabled', codeEnabled); // getting false always
    console.log('codeEnabledObj.length[0]', codeEnabledObj.length); // undefined

  })
  .catch((error) => {

  });
```

The issue is, It's not going inside if condition and throwing error like undefined.

But, If we print the response from db fetch

```
'codeEnabledObj', { type: 'codeStatus', isEnabled: true } // This is my response
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: where is this log in code? `'codeEnabledObj.length[0]', undefined`

Comment: firstly, what's the `codeEnabledObj.length[0]`? I guess that's typo. and are you sure your response is an array? codeEnabledObj Is looks like an object from your answer.

Comment: Please check updated query.

Comment: Your response isn't an array? why you checking the length?

Comment: even dictionary also we can check length, right? can't we?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects don't have length property like an array.

`codeEnabledObj.length` is wrong

use this,

```
 Object.keys(codeEnabledObj).length
```

**EDIT** :

`codeEnabledObj[0].isEnabled` should be only `codeEnabledObj.isEnabled`

Comment: But, If I tried to get codeEnabledObj values, still I am not able to get.

Answer (score 0):

There is no property length in the `codeEnabledObj` , Moreover its not an Array.. so modifying the condition would work, where isEmpty could be a function used from 
node package as `underscore`

```
if (isEmpty(codeEnabledObj)) { // ... }
```

and

```
codeEnabledObj.isEnabled
```

Thanks.